# Python loop wont iterate through dictionary correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I'm working on a personal finance program of mine and I'm trying to get the user to be able to select the currency they wish to deal in. I'm trying to do error handling where if the key they input does not exist in the dictionary it shows a message and closes the program. But now even when I input a correct key it still closes.

```
print("Currency's supported: USD, EUR, CAN, YEN, GBP")
currencyCheck = input("Input the currency you would like to use. Ex: 'USD' or 'EUR'...etc ").upper()


#currencySYM is a dictionary of currency ticker symbols and currency symbols
currencySYM = {'USD':'$', 'EUR':'€', 'CAN':'C$','YEN':'¥','GBP':'£'}
#the for loop takes the input from Currencycheck and applies the correct symbol to the letters
for key in currencySYM:
    if currencyCheck == key:
        currencyCheck = currencySYM[key]

    elif currencyCheck != key:
        print("Make sure you type the correct three letter symbol.")
        exit()
```

and if I take out the else statement it works but not as intended, I could type any word it would not have to be a key and it would assign it to the variable, not even checking if it exists as a key in the dictionary

Comment: Why does this loop exist? `if key in currencySYM: ....`

Comment: You are exiting after the first item doesn't match. You want to exit if no items match at all, but again the loop is not needed here.

Comment: Variable and function names should follow the `lower_case_with_underscores` style. Also, you used `exit()` but I think you might have been looking for `break` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to immediately break out after checking the first key. One fix may be

```
found = False

for key in currencySYM:
    if currencyCheck == key:
        currencyCheck = currencySYM[key]
        found = True

if !found:
    print("Make sure you type the correct three letter symbol.")
    exit()
```

Of course, the better way to do this would be to check if the key is in the dictionary:

```
if currencyCheck in currencySYM:
    currencyCheck = currencySYM[key]
else:
    print("Make sure you type the correct three letter symbol.")
    exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are checking that EVERY key in the dictionary has been input, which is impossible. You can easily fix this by adding a `break` statement at the end of the `if` clause:

```
 if currencyCheck == key:
    currencyCheck = currencySYM[key]
    # found the key, so stop checking
    break
```

In any case this code is not very pythonic, you can substitute the whole loop for this code, which will return None if the key is not available in the dict:

```
currencyCheck = currencySYM.get(key,None)
if not currencyCheck:
    print("Make sure you type the correct three letter symbol.")
    exit()
```

Comment: Thank you!, I guess I should read the guidelines on pythonic code

Answer (score 0):

If you want to check if a `key` exists in a given dictionary you can do this `key in dict`.

```
currencyCheck = input("Input the currency you would like to use. Ex: 'USD' or 'EUR'...etc ").upper()
currencySYM = {'USD':'$', 'EUR':'€', 'CAN':'C$','YEN':'¥','GBP':'£'}
if currenyCheck in currencySYM:
    currencyCheck = currencySYM[key]
else:
    exit()
```

Or you can use `.get()`.

```
currencyCheck = input("Input the currency you would like to use. Ex: 'USD' or 'EUR'...etc ").upper()
currencySYM = {'USD':'$', 'EUR':'€', 'CAN':'C$','YEN':'¥','GBP':'£'}

currencyCheck=currencySYM.get(currencyCheck,exit())
```

> ***Dictionaries*** are unordered - since the *values* in the ***dictionary are indexed by keys***, they are not held in any particular order, unlike a list, where each item can be located by its position in the list.

Comment: I guess I just had to assume I need a loop for dictionaries, thanks!

Comment: @WillArmentrout You want a solution using loop?

Answer (score 0):

That's should work:

```
currencyCheck = input("Input the currency you would like to use. Ex: 'USD' or 'EUR'...etc ").upper()

#currencySYM is a dictionary of currency ticker symbols and currency symbols
currencySYM = {'USD':'$', 'EUR':'€', 'CAN':'C$','YEN':'¥','GBP':'£'}
#the for loop takes the input from Currencycheck and applies the correct symbol to the letters
key_list = currencySYM.keys()
if currencyCheck in key_list:
    currencyCheck = currencySYM[currencyCheck]

elif currencyCheck not in key_list:
    print("Make sure you type the correct three letter symbol.")
    exit()
```